# Create a sequence in a complex type in XML and validate against a schema

Tags: xml, xsd

How do I write various repetitions of the elements that are part of a sequence which is inside a complex type?

I've got the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="Measurements">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Schema for Measurements data transmission</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="m_doc" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="m_parameters">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="m_name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_isEngValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="m_unit" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_radix" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I test the following XML against the previous schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Measurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <m_doc>TestDoc</m_doc>
    <m_parameters>

      <!-- First group -->
      <m_name>Length</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>HEXADECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>

      <!-- Second group -->
      <m_name>Height</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>DECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>

    </m_parameters>
</Measurements>
```

Getting this error:

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With
>   Element 'm_name'. No Child Element Is Expected At This Point., Line
>   '13', Column '15'.

This error is about the second group of 5 elements which constitute a parameter. If I remove this second group then I get no error.

I am trying with an online validator : [www.freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)

The schema is a requirement over which I have no control. I have to generate XML which will pass validation by that schema.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want to do is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common practice is to wrap each group into an element with an unbounded occurrence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Measurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <m_doc>TestDoc</m_doc>
  <m_parameters>
    <!-- First group -->
    <m_parameter>
      <m_name>Length</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>HEXADECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>
    </m_parameter>
  <!-- Second group -->
    <m_parameter>
      <m_name>Height</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>DECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>
    </m_parameter>
  </m_parameters>
</Measurements>
```

which means for the schema:

```
<xs:element name="m_parameters">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="m_parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="m_name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="m_isEngValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="m_unit" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="m_radix" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="m_value" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If you have no control over the schema though, I am afraid that repetition is not possible as `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` have the value 1 by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` as attributtes of `xs:sequence`

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="m_name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="m_isEngValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <xs:element name="m_unit" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="m_radix" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="m_value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergio. Though changing the schema is not a option in this case, client requirement. I need to write XML with more than 1 group of parameters which validates against the already existing schema.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see that last requirement, I don't think it can be done.